# views' constrains goes wrong after phone call, swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I added constraints from mainstoryboard to the views. I am adding some views as subviews such this code:

```
    let controller:profileOther = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileOther") as! profileOther
    controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    controller.willMoveToParentViewController(self)
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    self.addChildViewController(controller)
    controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

So normally I am adding views left and right side margin to 0 for added views. But the views which comes with segue I am setting -20 to right and left side margins. It works very well but the problem is when somebody calls me while I am using program If the added view was already open, all constraints goes wrong. If the view which comes from segue was opened constraints still work well. The views -expected and after phone call- are in the links. I will appreciate the answers. Thanks.

http://hizliresim.com/3LMAy5

http://hizliresim.com/WkabJP

Comment: Rather than setting constraints -20 relative to margins, simply set the constraints to 0 leading & trailing without the relative to margin.

Comment: It is zero but I still getting same results

Answer (score 0):

`func application(application: UIApplication, willChangeStatusBarFrame newStatusBarFrame: CGRect) {
    for window in UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows {
        if window.dynamicType.self.description().containsString("UITextEffectsWindow") {
            window.removeConstraints(window.constraints)
        }
    }
}`